# node js - module scope with variables and results of a function

Tags: arrays, node.js, module, scope, tostring

I need a bit of help understanding how to copy results from a function that I want to pass as a module.exports.. there is a problem of global and local scope here:

```
// Declare node.js module dependencies from API
var walk = require('walk'), 
    filter;

// Declare variables    
var files = []; 
var filteredFiles = []; 
var i = 0;
var fileextension = '.html';
var foldername = 'node_modules';
var filter = {
    followLinks: false
};
var walker = walk.walkSync(foldername, filter); 

var temp = [];

module.exports = {
    scanDirWithFil: function () {
        walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
            files.push(stat.name);
            if (files[i].indexOf(fileextension) != -1) { 
                filteredFiles.push(stat.name);
                console.log(files[i]);
                next();
                i++;
            }
            else { 
                next();
                i++;
            }
            console.log('Number of filtered files in array: ' + filteredfiles.length + ", Total number of files in array: " + files.length)
            return files, filteredFiles;
        });
        temp = files.toString();
        return temp;
    }
};
```

As one can see here, I'm trying to return the results for the function scanDirWithFil, however the return is through temp, which is from files.toString. That is where the problem lies. files becomes an empty array at the moment because of a scope problem. The files array returned from the walker.on method doesn't actually get brought outside the scope of itself..

If I'm correct in what I'm saying (that this is a scope problem).. may someone direct me or help me with a possible solution to this problem?

Thank you,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs, apparently calling `walker.on` causes the code to run asynchronously. So it's not a scope problem, instead the line `temp = files.toString()` is simply executed before the walker function executes. Therefore its only logical that the `files` array is empty.

In order to use `walker` in synchronous mode you need to do:

```
walker = walk.walkSync("/tmp", {
    listeners: {
        file: function (root, fileStats, next) {

        }
    }
});
```

See: https://github.com/coolaj86/node-walk

Comment: Thank you very much! So it was because the code was running asynchronously. Good to know.